# What do the '_glossary' and '_contents' directives do in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, markup

In documentation for many packages, including Sphinx itself, I see a directive at the start of certain files of the form

```
.. _<filename>:
```

For example, [many glossaries](http://sphinx-doc.org/_sources/glossary.txt) start with

```
.. _glossary:
```

What do these directives do and where are they documented?

---

Note that I this is omitted from, for example, my 'glossary.rst', then `:ref:glossary` links to the Python glossary at python.org, rather than my glossary, so the directive is doing something important.

Answer (score 1):

A directive such as `.. _glossary:` is a *label* that identifies a spot in the document (a link target).

A link to that spot is created with this markup: `` :ref:`glossary` ``. See http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#ref-role for details.

And yes, if you use the [intersphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/intersphinx.html) extension (configured like this: `intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('http://docs.python.org/2.7', None)}`) and use the above link without having defined your own `.. _glossary:` label, the resulting link in the output will indeed point to http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#glossary.